# How to exploit a POST-requested XSS when there is a CSRF protection on the website?

Tags: exploit, xss, csrf

Assuming the payload is:

```
<script>alert(1)</script>
```

however it seems like the CSRF protection prevent me to hijack other's user session, is there another possibility?

Comment: Look for a legitimate request where the payload is reflected, as with any XSS. I'm not sure why a session token would prevent CSRF requests, or why, if it did, it would affect your ability to find an XSS vulnerability. Finding XSS on a given site is very much a case of looking at the specific site.

Comment: @Matthew I meant a "security token". Doesn't it prevent CSRF attacks? However, I can manually trigger the XSS on the website (via POST request)

Comment: A session token is a value, usually stored in a cookie, which identifies the specific data associated with a given client device or account. CSRF attacks rely on browsers sending these automatically with all requests made to a given site. It is possible to have an anti-CSRF token too, which needs to be sent in another method (in POST data, URL parameter, custom header), but they're not equivalent terms. If you can manually trigger it, you've already exploited the issue, surely?

Comment: Yeah, it's that "anti-CSRF token" which is binded on the POST request. I'm learning a bit of this, and I'd like to make an exploiting PoC (an HTML code that exploits the issue by triggering the payload to the website).

Comment: If they've implemented the anti-CSRF protection properly, you shouldn't be able to create a standalone page which allows you to exploit XSS. You'd have to do it from a valid session, as part of a legitimate request to the application, with a valid anti-CSRF token. If they're using a per-session CSRF token, you'd be able to built a page which uses this and works while the current session is active, but that's the best you'd be able to do.

Comment: @Matthew what about of this? http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/03/exploiting-unexploitable-xss-with.html

Comment: @Walfrat fixed the question.

Comment: @Walfrat it's a sample.